# How should I say "if you still want to meet me after all"

Tags: grammar

Is まだ私に会いたい場合 right?
Because I think it sounds a little bit strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds a little like 'in the case that you still want to meet me', it's a bit awkward. You can simply say... 「まだ会いたかったら・・・」 which is 'If you still wanna meet...'.

In Japanese we don't really use 私 if it can be assumed from context.

Comment: Uhm...I see...
That's a simple sentence that always make me confused haha

Thank you very much, James!